# Get the amount of binary numbers that meet a criteria and are less than "x"

Tags: c#, binary

I am trying to get the count (just a number, not a list) of  binary numbers that contain exactly 3 ones and that are less than 1000000000 ie: 10011, 100000011 and so on.

The code below works for integers, but how can I make it work with binary?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int con = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        string test = i.ToString();
        int count = test.Split('1').Length - 1;

        if (count == 3)
        {
            con++;
        }

    }

    Console.WriteLine(con);
}
```

Comment: The question is not very clear, add an example of what you want to get.

Comment: i just want a plain number, the amount of times that happens, i just put "con" in the writeline but it may be "'the amount of binary numbers with three "1" in them is ' +con"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to alter your code would be:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{

    int con = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
    {
        string test = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
        int count = test.Split('1').Length - 1;

        if (count == 3)
        {
            con++;
        }

    }

    Console.WriteLine(con);
}
```

This could be done as a pure mathematical equation though:

```
9! / (6!*3!) = 84
```

Answer (score 3):

And for your continued education, here's *another* way to solve the problem.  We wish to know how many binary strings there are with exactly `on` on bits and `off` off bits.

There are some easy problems to solve in there. `N(on, off)` is equal to one if `on` and `off` are both zero, because the only solution is the empty string. And if either is zero then the answer is one, because the string that is all zeros or all ones is unique.

Let's start tabulating this in a table.

```
         on
      0  1  2  3  4  5
   +---------------------   
o 0|  1  1  1  1  1  1
f 1|  1
f 2|  1
  3|  1
  4|  1
  5|  1
  6|  1
```

Now what should go at (1, 1)?  Well, the number of binary strings that have one on and one off bit is equal to the number of such strings that start with one, plus the number of such strings that start with zero.  So we have:

```
N(1, 1) = N(1, 0) + N(0, 1) = 2
```

What about N(2, 1) ?  Same deal:

```
N(2, 1) = N(1, 1) + N(2, 0) = 3
```

And we can see that similarly N(x, 1) =  N(1, x) = x + 1.  Fill in the array:

```
          on
      0  1  2  3  4  5
   +---------------------   
o 0|  1  1  1  1  1  1
f 1|  1  2  3  4  5  6
f 2|  1  3
  3|  1  4
  4|  1  5
  5|  1  6
  6|  1  7
```

in general for on, off not zero:

```
N(on, off) = N(on - 1, off) + N(on, off - 1)
```

which means that we can fill in this entire array by repeatedly applying this rule.  **Can you write a program which does so**?

Once you do, you can simply read your answer out of the array at `[6, 3]`.

**Have you seen this pattern in this array before?**  It has a name.  Hint: you probably have not seen it laid out as a square.

Answer (score 2):

For your amusement and education, consider the following:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Combinations(int on, int off) 
{
  if (on == 0 && off == 0)
    yield return "";
  if (on > 0)
    foreach(var s in Combinations(on - 1, off))
      yield return "1" + s;
  if (off > 0)
    foreach(var s in Combinations(on, off - 1))
      yield return "0" + s;
}
```

Study this implementation: it yields a sequence of binary strings with `on` bits on and `off` bits off. Do you see how it does so?

Plainly calling `.Count()` on this thing solves your problem, though such a solution is enormously less efficient than simply doing the math.

I present this for your study because a recursive enumerator such as this one is a powerful tool when investigating permutations and combinations.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without resorting to string representations:

```
static int CountBits(int i)
{
    var current = i;
    var bits = 0;

    while (current != 0)
    {
        if ((current & 1) == 1)
        {
            bits += 1;
        }

        current >>= 1;
    }

    return bits;
}
```

With this helper method, the count is easy:

```
var count = Enumerable.Range(0, 0b1000000000)
                      .Count(i => CountBits(i) == 3);
```

And the answer is 84.

Comment: Note that you can do a little better by taking advantage of the fact that         `current &= current - 1;` clears the bottom set bit; instead of checking each bit one at a time you can run this statement in a loop and count how many times it takes to get `current` to zero.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks! I’m hopelessly bad when it comes to bit twiddling.

Answer (score 0):

Long code (grumpy style)

```
var con = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    var test = i.ToString();
    if (test.Count(x => x == '1') == 3)
    {
        con++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(con);
```

Shorter (more mature)

```
var con = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000)
         .Select(x => $"{x:00000}")
         .Count(x => 
             x.Count(c => c == '1') == 3
         );

Console.WriteLine(con);
```

PS: They both seem to have the same performance.

Comment: The user wants to test binary numbers not decimal numbers.